# Spring Boot Security with Database Users not logging in

Tags: spring-boot

I have tried everything I can think of to get this working. I've tried the techniques in my books, countless online tutorials and examples, and no matter what I do I am not having success. I have been trying to figure this out for weeks now.

This is the closest I have gotten. I get prompted with the login page when I try to access the /users GetMapping, as expected, but I get a 403 forbidden error after entering credentials, so I believe my credentials are correct and perhaps there is some sort of problem with the role? I have already disabled csrf as per the suggestions on other stack overflow answers. I am getting a bit desperate and I apologize for my ignorance. Here is what I currently have (this implementation is from one of my books)

Note: All of the components and functionality work properly when I remove the security classes and dependencies. I am at a loss. If you can help I would be forever grateful.

Main application:

```
package com.madhax.website;

import com.madhax.website.domain.Article;
import com.madhax.website.domain.User;
import com.madhax.website.service.ArticleService;
import com.madhax.website.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsiteApplication {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return args -> {

            User myUser = new User(
                    "admin",
                    "$2a$04$C/mOkKfXtOhKjhnUUrwp3OcWzLHJqkGzYpV1oys.MBPXc9M8soAQ6",
                    "USER");
            myUser.setFirstName("James");
            myUser.setLastName("Cathcart");
            userService.saveUser(myUser);

            Article article1 = new Article(
                    "Example Article 1 Title",
                    "Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora " +
                    "torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, " +
                    "urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis " +
                    "turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus " +
                    "consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices.",
                    myUser);
            articleService.saveArticle(article1);

            Article article2 = new Article(
                    "Example Article 1 Title",
                    "Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora " +
                            "torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, " +
                            "urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis " +
                            "turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus " +
                            "consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices.",
                    myUser);
            articleService.saveArticle(article2);

            Article article3 = new Article(
                    "Example Article 1 Title",
                    "Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora " +
                            "torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, " +
                            "urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis " +
                            "turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus " +
                            "consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices.",
                    myUser);
            articleService.saveArticle(article3);

            Article article4 = new Article(
                    "Example Article 1 Title",
                    "Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora " +
                            "torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, " +
                            "urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis " +
                            "turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus " +
                            "consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices.",
                    myUser);
            articleService.saveArticle(article4);

        };
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
package com.madhax.website.config;

import com.madhax.website.service.UserDetailServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users", "/users/**")
                    .hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin();
    }
}
```

UserDetailServiceImpl

```
package com.madhax.website.service;

import com.madhax.website.domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User currentUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        UserDetails user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                username,
                currentUser.getPassword(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(currentUser.getRole()));
        return user;
    }
}
```

UserRepository:

```
package com.madhax.website.service;

import com.madhax.website.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserService:

```
package com.madhax.website.service;

import com.madhax.website.domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<User> getUserById(long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }
}
```

User:

```
package com.madhax.website.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;

    public User() { }

    public User(String username, String password, String role) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefix your role with `ROLE_` as per the documentation [Spring security doc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in) (emphasis mine)

> hasRole([role])
>
> Returns true if the current principal has the specified role. **By
>   default if the supplied role does not start with 'ROLE_' it will be
>   added**. This can be customized by modifying the defaultRolePrefix on
>   DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.

So try using `ROLE_USER` instead of just `USER` when you create your user or configure the defaultRolePrefix to be empty string